# I don’t know what the purpose of Stack Overflow is

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, down-votes, post-ban

First of all apologies to all. I don’t know what the purpose of Stack Overflow. I thought Stack Overflow is used discourage and tease the beginner level developers.

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15479971) on your website, your higher level member closed the question. He does not understand what I am asking you. Perhaps my question was wrong, please be correct the question or personally warn me. But instead why do they downvote and write teasing comments? It would hurt and discourage me. Please be sure to consider, you were all beginners when you started your careers.

Now, my "ask question" button was locked this time. I need to ask some questions, what I can do? I think Stack Overflow wants more fake accounts. Am I correct?

Comment: whose gives negative votes . I think they are not read my ques...

Comment: *I thought stack overflow is used to discourage and tease the beginner level developers*. I sincerely wonder how you came to that conclusion. Yes, we do close questions in order to maintain the quality level of the site, but that does not mean we aim to discourage or mock the questioners. People improve, bad questions usually don't.

Comment: Also, [downvotes on meta express disagreement](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences). It only means people do not agree with you. Did you read the FAQ before asking here?

Comment: ok leave it simply i don't like your website . How can i delete my account..

Comment: Which question are you referring to? ([this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15539743/return-multiple-values-from-a-single-method-in-c-sharp)?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479971/what-is-difference-between-initiate-a-class-and-inherit-a-class see the url

Comment: @Niventh - You can find instructions for deleting your account [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account).

Comment: @JackManey thanks a lot..........

Comment: @Niventh - You're welcome.

Comment: @Niventh: that question wasn't closed.

Comment: @DavidRobinson thanks i think this question will reach maximum downvotes votes

Comment: @Niventh - There is no such thing as a maximum number of downvotes for a question. That being said, this question's score is unlikely to go much below -40.

Comment: @JackManey Challenge accepted.

Comment: No stack overflow is one of the best sites. I have asked very basic questions and they were solved very satisfactory. No one can help you if you can't explain your problem.

Answer (score 12):

I'm going to go ahead and answer this by saying that I think you're being overly harsh.

You have 3 questions on SO that I can see at the moment, and I can find *very* little in the way of bad behaviour on the part of other users.

[Performance analyze for loop and foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462145/performance-analyze-for-loop-and-foreach)

- closed as duplicate. This is normal, we actively try to link back to the canonical answer for any sort of question
- it is not a good fit for SO, it has no definitive answer

The comments are:

1. Some advice on how to better profile the performance in question
2. Another hint at something which may have affected your test
3. Yet another helpful comment on how to better gauge performance differences

All polite!

[What is different between initiate a class and inherit a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479971/what-is-different-between-initiate-a-class-and-inherit-a-class)

- Another terrible question, showing that you have NOT read the FAQ.
- Answered in-depth by Eric Lippert. Protip: you won't get a better answer!

Comments are:

1. Irrelevant, but not rude
2. A hint to use a less contrived example.
3. You pointing out you are new to C#. That's fine
4. A request for clarification
5. A slightly terse, but not rude comment
6. A reminder from Eric Lippert that beginner questions shouldn't be derided as we were all beginners once
7. An apology for the terseness.

Nothing particularly rude.

[Return multiple values from a single method in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15539743/return-multiple-values-from-a-single-method-in-c-sharp)

- A terrible question, showing no research effort or even attempt at properly describing the question
- Correctly (IMO) closed as NARQ

Comments are:

1. A good bit of advice, again from Eric Lippert. You've hit the jackpot buddy, this guy is answering your poor questions even though he should be using effort elsewhere IMO!
2. Duplicate notice

---

Now, tell me again why you feel we are out to get newbies? Seems like you've had the world's best advice. Also seems that you haven't done the one thing everyone new to any community should do - read the FAQ.

Comment: Perhaps my question was wrong please be correct the question or personally warned me. But instead why they are gives negative votes and wrote teased comments. It would be hurt me and discouraging me.

Comment: To be fair, there were a couple of pretty insulting comments which have since been scrubbed. You don't see those when looking at the questions now.

Comment: @Niventh Please realize that *because* your question was answered by Eric Lippert, it likely attracted more attention than other questions.

Comment: @BradLarson - Im sure there were. I hope that the appropriate action was taken in order to remind those users whose comments were deleted about the need to be nice on SO!